# How set the same height of divs

Tags: css

This is my situation

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="item1">
        <div class="empty">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="empty">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="empty">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div id="item2">
        <div class="empty">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.empty
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

#item1
{
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: green;
}

#item2
{
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#content
{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: pink;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This looks that http://jsfiddle.net/59qEt/3/

So my question is: How I must set my styles to #item2 has the same height which #item1 have?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Answer can be found on this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988381/equal-height-divs-two-column/15584074#15584074

Comment: You can find the answer on this stack:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988381/equal-height-divs-two-column/15584074#15584074

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **display:table-cell** property for this. and remove `float:left` write like this:

```
#item1, #item2
{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/59qEt/5/

Note it's work till IE8 & above.

Answer (score 0):

in item 1 you are using 3 `div` each `div` with `padding:10px;` and in item 2 just 1 `div` you can do 2 thing 1 in item 2 add 3 `div` and option 2. apply `height` on item 2 and item 2 child empty

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
#item2 > div {
    padding-bottom:200px;
}
```

Here's the fiddle for this :

http://jsfiddle.net/59qEt/24/

Answer (score 0):

remove the item2 from css
`

```
<div id="item1">
    <div class="empty">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="empty">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="empty">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div id="item1">
    <div class="empty">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

`

Answer (score -1):

Just add two string of JavaScript **http://jsfiddle.net/59qEt/20/**
Works in all browsers