# How to I make my the height of my sidebar and main content consistent?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Currently I'm using wordpress for my website. The height of my sidebar and main content area doesn't align. How to I make the height of my sidebar and the main content consistent? Example pageA has longer content but the sidebar is shorter, so the unused sidebar area will fill up with blank white space.

Below is my index.php code.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
  <div id="table">
      <div id="mainsidebar">
          <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
      </div>
      <div id="maincontent">
          <div valign="top">
            <?php wowslider(9); ?>
          </div>
          <div valign="bottom">
            <?php include('main-content.php'); ?>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
</body>
```

Here the sample image link that I've uploaded.

[image: http://imgur.com/uy6bOK2]

Thanks.

Comment: Answer can be found in this post :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988381/equal-height-divs-two-column/15584074#15584074

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using javascript:

```
$(function(){
    var main = $('#maincontent').height(),
        sidebar = $('#mainsidebar').height();
    if(main > sidebar){
        $('#mainsidebar').css({'min-height':main});
    }
});
```

Comment: @Pey, I know this is a late reply but I found this useful for a project I'm currently working on where a CSS solution was not possible. This would need to go into an external .js file and linked in the footer of your site, or wrap it in `<script> [code here] </script>` tags and place in the footer

Answer (score 0):

I use [equalize.js](http://tsvensen.github.com/equalize.js/) for this. Super simple to setup and works fantastically!

Answer (score 0):

Put `<div id="mainsidebar"></div>` and `<div id="maincontent"></div>` in another div. Make that div as same height of `maincontent` div. and give `height:100%` for `mainsidebar` div.

Idea from [here](http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/117/sidebar-same-heightlength-as-main-content-area/p1).

Answer (score 0):

As posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-divs-that-are-side-by-side-the-same-height), you can do this with CSS:

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.column {
    float: left;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: grey;
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">Some content!
        <br/>Some content!
        <br/>Some content!
        <br/>Some content!
        <br/>Some content!
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div class="column">Something</div>
</div>
```

Or try the following:

From: [Two floating divs side by side, same height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556856/two-floating-divs-side-by-side-same-height)

HTML:

```
<div id="table">
    <div id="mainsidebar">
        <p>Main Sidebar Content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="maincontent">
        <p>Main Content</p>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#table { position: relative; }

#mainsidebar { /* shorter column */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    width: 38%;
    padding: 2%;
}
#maincontent { /* taller column */
    margin: 0 0 0 42%;
    width: 58%;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

You don`t need to make it the same height.
Set table background "white" and it will look like both have the same height

```
#table {background: #fff;}
```